# Reverse delegates

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to do reverse delegation in Ruby (although fully aware that might not even be a thing.) To illustrate, say I have two classes:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @bar = Bar.new
  end

  def say_hello
    @bar.say_hello
  end

  def greeting
    "OHAI"
  end
end

class Bar
  def say_hello
    puts greeting
  end

  def greeting
    "Hello!"
  end
end
```

How would I go about making a macro method on `Foo` that tells `Bar` to use `Foo`'s `greeting` method?

Comment: *macro* method means ?

Comment: Such a twisted design .. one could override the (`@bar`) object's ["eigenclass" method](http://timnew.github.io/blog/2012/05/25/open-eigenclass-in-ruby/), but *ick*. It is generally better to avoid this cyclic design. (A more obvious example of the cyclic design can be seen when solving this by passing the instance of `Foo` to the `Bar` initializer.)

Comment: Kinda fits the purpose. The end goal is to "patch" a sexp parser class that emits events through method calls and have those mapped to mine so I can wrap them with custom classes.

Comment: These are instance methods. Do you mean you want a particular instance of Bar to send `greeting` to a particular instance of Foo, or do you want Bar to literally have the same instance method?

Comment: Why do you say "possible duplicate", @sawa?  I'd think calling a method in a class' superclass is quite different.  Among other things, you can't use `alias`, as was employed in the chosen answer to the question you cited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `class Bar` as follows:

```
class Bar
  def say_hello
    puts greeting
  end

  def use_foos_greeting
    self.class.class_eval do
      def greeting
        @f ||= Foo.new
        @f.greeting
      end
    end  
  end

  def use_bars_greeting
    self.class.class_eval do
      alias_method :greeting, :greeting_copy
    end  
  end

  def greeting
    "Hello!"
  end

  alias_method :greeting_copy, :greeting
end

bar = Bar.new
bar.greeting          #=> "Hello!"
bar.use_foos_greeting
bar.greeting          #=> "OHAI"
bar.use_bars_greeting
bar.greeting          #=> "Hello!"
```

Consider the method:

```
def use_foos_greeting
  self.class.class_eval do
    def greeting
      @f ||= Foo.new
      @f.greeting
    end
  end  
end
```

Here

```
@f ||= Foo.new
```

is shorthand for

```
@f = @f || Foo.new
```

The first time `use_foos_greeting` is called, `@f => nil`, so `@f` is set to `Foo.new`.  In following calls to `use_foos_greeting`, `@f` evaluate `true`, so it will not be changed.  The method would work if we had `@f = Foo.new` instead, but a new instance of `Foo` would be created each time the method were called (and the instance of `Foo` it replaced would be garbage-collected).

Note you cannot add:

```
def initialize
  @f = Foo.new
end
```

to `class Bar` to save the `Foo` instance, because class `Foo` has

```
def initialize
  @f = Bar.new
end
```

which would result in an endless loop.